# Каталог на главной странице Wordpress при обновлении скролит наверх

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть сайт на Wordpress, в качестве плагина для создания интернет магазина использую Woocommerce.

По задаче, необходимо, чтобы на главной странице сайта, после нескольких блоков, чуть ниже располагался сам каталог, вставленный шорткодом Woocommerce.

Теперь проблема. Когда пользователь выбирает что-то в каталоге, меняет категорию, листает страницы, в общем, делает любые манипуляции с каталогом, то страница как бы обновляется и перекидывает пользователя наверх. Вот хочу это поправить.

Может сталкивался кто и знает решение? Или хотя бы куда копать?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вероятней всего навигация по каталогу работает как загрузка новой страницы. Поэтому и происходит перезагрузка страницы с каталогом, а при загрузке новой станицы ее просмотр начинается сначала.

Если есть возможность включить или настроить навигацию через AJAX - нужно это сделать - это должно помочь и переходы будут без загрузки страницы.

Костыльный вариант - сделать чтобы перезагрузка происходила с якорем и после загрузки страница автоматически скролилас к блоку с каталогом.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Через AJAX попробую обязательно, а якорем пробовал, но ничего путного не вышло)

Comment: Попробовал, но к сожалению не помогло. Изменяется сайдбар и не обновляется страница, а сам контент не обновляется. Буду еще тестить, но пока результатов не дало.